# Which Chroma to use for my setup?

Tags: appletv

I have AppleTV 4K and Sony X900E. AppleTV picked Chroma 4:2:0 with an option to select 4:2:2

Which one to use? I don’t know what those are supposed to do but I just want to take the most of my setup

Answer (score 2):

To give a generalized answer, the larger the numbers, the better. However, some material may be optimized for 4:2:0.

Some Sony TVs are able to handle 4:4:4 (no subsampling) when enhanced mode is enabled, check if you can enable this for optimal signal.

- Press the HOME button on the remote control
- Select Settings
- Select External inputs in the TV category
- Select HDMI signal format and set to Enhanced format